# getting Null value from on Servlet from request.getParameter() from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am sending text values from jsp to servlet but in servlet request.getParameter() gives me null values. Below I am mentioning my JSP, Servlet and web.xml

```
REGISTER.JSP  
<form id="contactform"  action="servlet/SaveInfo" method="post"> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="email">Email</label></p> 
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="" tabindex="1" type="email">

    <p class="contact"><label for="username">User Name</label></p> 
    <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required="" tabindex="2" type="text"> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="password">Password</label></p> 
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="" tabindex="3"> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="repassword">Confirm  Password</label></p> 
    <input type="password" id="repassword" name="repassword" required=""> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="phone">Mobile Phone</label></p> 
             <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone number" required="" tabindex="4" type="text"> <br>

    <p class="contact"><label for="name">Organization Name</label></p> 
            <input id="Orgname" name="name" placeholder="Organization name" required="" tabindex="5" type="text"> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="Address">Address</label></p> 
            <input id="address" name="name" placeholder="Street,Area,city" required="" tabindex="6" type="text"> <br>


    <!--     <select class="select-style" name="BirthMonth"> -->
            <label>State</label><br>
             <select  class="select-style" name="BirthMonth">
              <%
                        ResultSet rs = null;
                                Connection con = null;
                                            PreparedStatement pmst1= null;
                                           int countryid = 208;
                                           try{

                                              con = DBConnectivity.getOracleDBConnection();
                                              pmst1 = con.prepareStatement(Sqlquery.getRegion());

                                             pmst1.setInt(1, countryid);
                                             rs=pmst1.executeQuery();

                                           while(rs.next()){
                                               String name = rs.getString("name"); 
                                               %>
                                              <option value="<%=name %>"><%=name %></option>

                                         <%   }   %>     

                                           <%
                                          }catch(Exception e){
                                         }                                                     

                                %>

           </select><br><br>



        <p class="contact"> <input id="check" name="name" style="margin-right: 10px" type="checkbox">
        <label for="name"> Not Yet Registered GSTIN</label> </p>


        <p class= "GSTIN"><label for="GSTIN">GSTIN No.</label></p><br>
        <input id = "GSTINNO" maxlength="15"  name= "GSTIN" placeholder="GSTIN No." type ="text"><br><br>

        <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Sign me up!" type="submit">
```

```
SaveInfo.java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {          
     try{
             ResultSet rs = null;
             Connection con = null;
             PreparedStatement pmst1= null;
             String Orgname =  request.getParameter("Orgname");  
             String check =request.getParameter("check");
             String GSTINNO =  request.getParameter("GSTINNO");
             con = DBConnectivity.getOracleDBConnection();
             int   clientid = 1000014;
             MClient Client = new MClient (Env.getCtx(), clientid, null);
```

I want all the values in my servlet class and save that values in database below I am mentioning my web.xml file
Kindly help me out

```
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>SaveInfo</display-name>  
<servlet-name>SaveInfo</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>com.org.register.SaveInfo</servlet-class>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>SaveInfo</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/servlet/SaveInfo</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You are using wrong name with **input** tag in your JSP, please verify those. For example there is nothing called **Orgname** in your JSP. that's why you are getting null for that.

Comment: You will find a complete explanation about [HTML form on mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Comment: Lina, just for letting you know, you cannot accept two answers for one question here. Only one answer per question is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getParameter function of request object works with name attribute. So please replace your jsp with following.

```
<form id="contactform"  action="servlet/SaveInfo" method="post"> 

        <p class="contact"><label for="email">Email</label></p> 
        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="" tabindex="1" type="email">

        <p class="contact"><label for="username">User Name</label></p> 
        <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required="" tabindex="2" type="text"> 

          <p class="contact"><label for="password">Password</label></p> 
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="" tabindex="3"> 

         <p class="contact"><label for="repassword">Confirm  Password</label></p> 
        <input type="password" id="repassword" name="repassword" required=""> 

        <p class="contact"><label for="phone">Mobile Phone</label></p> 
         <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone number" required="" tabindex="4" type="text"> <br>

        <p class="contact"><label for="name">Organization Name</label></p> 
        <input id="Orgname" name="Orgname" placeholder="Organization name" required="" tabindex="5" type="text"> 

         <p class="contact"><label for="Address">Address</label></p> 
        <input id="address" name="address" placeholder="Street,Area,city" required="" tabindex="6" type="text"> <br>


    <!--     <select class="select-style" name="BirthMonth"> -->
        <label>State</label><br>
         <select  class="select-style" name="BirthMonth">
          <%
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                            Connection con = null;
                                        PreparedStatement pmst1= null;
                                       int countryid = 208;
                                       try{

                                          con = DBConnectivity.getOracleDBConnection();
                                          pmst1 = con.prepareStatement(Sqlquery.getRegion());

                                         pmst1.setInt(1, countryid);
                                         rs=pmst1.executeQuery();

                                       while(rs.next()){
                                           String name = rs.getString("name"); 
                                           %>
                                          <option value="<%=name %>"><%=name %></option>

                                     <%   }   %>     

                                       <%
                                      }catch(Exception e){
                                     }                                                     

                            %>

       </select><br><br>



    <p class="contact"> <input id="check" name="name" style="margin-right: 10px" type="checkbox">
    <label for="name"> Not Yet Registered GSTIN</label> </p>


    <p class= "GSTIN"><label for="GSTIN">GSTIN No.</label></p><br>
    <input id = "GSTINNO" maxlength="15"  name= "GSTIN" placeholder="GSTIN No." type ="text"><br><br>

    <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Sign me up!" type="submit">
```

Comment: it is not necessary to post the complete code, just saying where annd what is the problem, with an example of correction is enough ;)

Comment: Dude I am developer and I understand the pain of other developers, stack overoverflow is a platform where developer come seeking for quick solution. So I write my answer in two parts, 1. pointing out mistake 2. give quick fix (Copy paste).. Hope you understand

Answer (score 2):

In Servlet you need to get parameters by `name` attribute, not `id`.

For example, You have the following,

```
<input id="Orgname" name="name" placeholder="Organization name" required="" tabindex="5" type="text">
```

Here you have given `id` to be `Orgname` and `name` parameter is `name`. So in Servlet you will do,

```
request.getParameter("name");
```

But you are doing,

```
String Orgname =  request.getParameter("Orgname");
```

Secondly, you cannot have same name for two parameters. For both the following you have given name to be name

```
<input id="Orgname" name="name" placeholder="Organization name" required="" tabindex="5" type="text"> 

<input id="address" name="name" placeholder="Street,Area,city" required="" tabindex="6" type="text"> <br>
```

Give some different name to the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

JSP post parameters using their attribute name. you wrote the wrong attribute name in 3 parameters.

Change:

```
<input id="check" name="name"
<input id="Orgname" name="name"
<input id="address" name="name"
```

To:

```
<input id="check" name="check"
<input id="Orgname" name="Orgname"
<input id="address" name="address"
```

Comment: You might need to add what is the problem, why is that, what to correction is and do ...

Comment: added explanation